# Set layout with JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, null-layout-manager

I haven't really worked with Swing at all in Java. I'm experimenting with it. I want to make a set layout that the size can't be changed. I've seen alot of things suggesting to use `Layout managers` to add multiple `JPanels` into a `JFrame`.

However, all the tutorials I've seen involving layout managers say it allows for the user to resize the screen. The layout I want has a rectangle going along the left hand side, a  thin rectangle going along the bottom, and a third rectangle taking up the rest of the space. I attempting it using an Absolute layout but it just doesn't want to work for me.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        JPanel rect1 = new JPanel();
        rect1.setBounds(101, 650, 900, 50);
        rect1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        getContentPane().add(rect1);

        JPanel rect2 = new JPanel();
        rect2.setBounds(0, 650, 100, 1000);
        rect2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        getContentPane().add(rect2);

        JPanel rect3 = new JPanel();
        rect3.setBounds(101, 700, 900, 950);
        rect3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        getContentPane().add(rect3);

       setTitle("TEST");
       setSize(1000, 700);

       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test ex = new Test();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone help me properly make three Jpanels in a Jframe in this layout (all with different colors)?

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to achieve the same thing using a `BorderLayout` as the bases or even a `GridBagLayout`.

The main piece you are missing is the fact that layout managers use (or can use depending on the layout manager) the component's preferred/minimum/maximum size

Basically, what you would do is define a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and override it's `getPreferredSize` method and return the required value you need.  Depending on the layout manager, you may also need to override the `getMaximumSize` and `getMinimumSize` methods as well.

For example...

Basically, this shows the "default" size and what happens when the screen is resized...

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FixedSizeLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FixedSizeLayout();
    }

    public FixedSizeLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(new ContentPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new LeftPane(), gbc);
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(new BottomPane(), gbc);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        public ContentPane() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(150, 150);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

    }

    public class BottomPane extends JPanel {

        public BottomPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

    }

    public class LeftPane extends JPanel {

        public LeftPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 150);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, if you prefer, you can make the screen non-resizable, but I for one won't like you.  I prefer to use the power of the layout managers and allow users to make decisions about how they want to view the content ... where I can ... but that's just me (I don't like non-resizable windows except in the case of some dialogs)

Comment: answer me 1 Question. When do you sleep ?

Comment: Now, i really feel sad for not being able to post the question such that i could upvote and accept the answer. :P. Anyway challenge accepted. :| :))

Comment: @sage Keep putting up quality answers as you are ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use setResizable(). Please refer to below code fragment.

```
   setResizable(false); // this will not allow resizing
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`AbsoluteLayout` is no go. Don't do that. You are probably looking for `BorderLayout`. Check the tutorial: [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for details. If you don't want your `JFrame` to be able to re-size use `frame.setResizable(false);` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `BorderLayout` and it will resize automatically:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(greenPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(redPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.add(bluePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MigLayout and replace BorderLayout.CENTER by "dock center":

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(" insets 0"));
panel.add(greenPanel, "dock center");
panel.add(redPanel, "dock south");
panel.add(bluePanel, "dock east");
```

Read more about MigLayout here: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf